# Dropzone doesn't queue more than one item

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, dropzone.js

I'm trying to rename files before upload with my dialog to get user input for file, but when I select more than one item it gives them the same name (when multiple selected) or doesn't queue anything, but the first file.

Dropzone configuration:

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#file_section", {maxFiles: 3,
    parallelUploads: 1, url: "assets/php/upload.php",
    accept: function (file,done) {
        bumm(file.name);
        async function bumm(text) {
            await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                showtextinput(text,function (value) {
                    uploadname = value;
                    resolve();
                    done();
                },function () {
                    alert('false');
                    reject(Error("It broke"));
                });
            });
        }
        filecount++;
        console.log("bitti");
    }});
myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
    /* Maybe display some more file information on your page */
    formData.append('newname',uploadname);
    uploadname=null;
});
myDropzone.on("success", function(file, xhr, formData) {
    /* Maybe display some more file information on your page */
    formData = new FormData();
});
```

Showtextinput function:

```
  function showtextinput(message, yesCallback, noCallback) {
    $('#inputlabel').html(message+" isimli dosyanın ne hakkında olduğunu kısaca giriniz..");
    $('#inputmodal').modal('show');

    $('#inputdone').click(function() {
        $('#inputmodal').modal('hide');
        yesCallback($('#textinput').val());
        $('#textinput').val = "";
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you are doing it right now, there is no point in using a `Promise` because you are not awaiting it. `new Promise` executes the code within the Promise synchronously and your `async function bumm` doesn't return anything.

I assume that you want a kind of queue so there is only one modal shown at a time. I suggest you introduce a variable to hold the respectively last promise and append a new promise with `.then()`:

```
var lastPromise = Promise.resolve(); // required to append the first dialog promise
```

and then instead of `bumm(file.name);` you do it like this

```
lastPromise = lastPromise.then(function() { return bumm(file.name); });
```

This way the dialog will only open when the last one was closed. Of course the `bumm()` function must return the promise:

```
function bumm(text) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // ...
    }
}
```